# Linux Asterisk script for test call

Tags: linux, asterisk, voip

I need to measure the MOS and quality of the VOIP service in a network. I want to create a script that simulates calls and then measure the networks metrics.

I'm using asterisk.

Do you have any suggestion about how to script and schedulate test calls with asterisk?

I would like to make calls of different duration maybe using some avi files.

Obviously I need to automate both outgoing call and automatic answer to that outgoing calls.

Comment: Question too broad. What exactly not work for you? Have you checked asterisk book? Asterisk dialout article on voip-info.org wiki?

Comment: I understood the automatic dialout for asterisk but not how to make automatic answer on other peers. I want to simulate a call between to person not just automatic dialout.

Comment: Sorry, that is out of topic here. You have show your effort and ask question. What is your question? answer on asterisk you can do by "Answer" dialplan command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using [Asterisk Call Files](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Using+Callfiles+and+Local+Channels)

Create a file name `/tmp/example.call` such as:

```
Channel: SIP/peerdevice/1234
Application: Playback
Data: silence/1&tt-weasels
```

And then copy that file and move it into the asterisk outgoing spool, such as:

```
cp /tmp/example.call /tmp/example.call.new
mv /tmp/example.call.new /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing
```

You'll notice at the Asterisk CLI it will originate a new call.

You can make another asterisk box answer the call automatically by saying to answer it in the dialplan, e.g. If you have another device `SIP/peerdevice`, and you're dialing 1234 per my example, in your dialplan:

```
[somecontext]
exten => 1234,1,Answer()
same =>       n,Noop(Example call inbound)
same =>       n,Playback(hello-world)
same =>       n,Hangup()
```

And you could create multiple extensions to do what you like to vary the behavior of the call.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the originate command, such as:

```
ast*CLI> channel originate SIP/755XXXXX@sip-outbound extension s@context_name
```

Which can also be issued from a shell as:

```
[user@host]$ asterisk -rx 'channel originate SIP/755XXXXX@sip-outbound extension s@context_name'
```

`SIP/755XXXXX@sip-outbound` = Is what device to use when dialing out so this could be IAX.,SIP,DAHDI following a slash and phone number

`extension` = Is required for the command. You may also use `application` followed by an Asterisk application, a la `channel originate SIP/device/1234 application playback tt-monkeys` which would playback a sound file.

`s` = This is what extension to send to within the context specified below

`@context_name` = Which context to send to in `extensions.conf`

[More information available in this Asterisk guide](http://asteriskguide.quora.com/OBD-Call-using-Asterisk-CLI)

Answer (score 0):

In case you will call a asterisk extension:

```
asterisk -rx "console dial extension@context"
```